# Trying To Set String in Listview

Tags: android

I am trying to set my string in `ListView` but `list.setadpter(adapter)` is giving an error is there any way to do it??Please help me 
Getting error on this line
next.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.id.Sorah, surah.toCharArray()));

```
enter code herepackage com.example.ahsan.quranapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.ahsan.quranapp.api.MyAPI;
import com.example.ahsan.quranapp.model.Ayah;
import com.example.ahsan.quranapp.model.MyResponse;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Response;
public class Next extends AppCompatActivity{
Retrofit retrofit;
MyAPI service;
ListView next;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sorah);
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.globalquran.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    service = retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Intent i2 = getIntent();
    String str =i2.getStringExtra("str");

    //final EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ayah);
    //final String str = ed.getText().toString().trim();
    //final String str = num.toString().trim();
        Call<MyResponse> call = service.getSurah(str);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {

                next  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Sorah);

                List<Ayah> list = new ArrayList<Ayah>(response.body().getQuran().getQuranSimple().values());
                String surah = "";

                for (Ayah ayah: list) {
                    surah += ayah.getSurah() + ":" + ayah.getAyah() + " ";
                    surah += ayah.getVerse() + '\n';
                }
                surah = surah.replace("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                next.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.id.Sorah, surah.toCharArray()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.verse);
                tv.setText("Op Failed");
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: set the Adapter and find the ListView inside onCreate . You can add data to it later.

Comment: Also, you have an `Ayah` class, so extend an `ArrayAdapter<Ayah>` in your own class to make a [custom adapter layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Answer (score 0):

Change the setAdapter like this way ->

```
next.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, surah.toCharArray()));
```

The problem here you have to use android default item list when you use `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: Still getting error can't resolve constructor(Arrayadapter annoy namus reterogit2.callback,myclass package name,int,char[])

Comment: You can see Surah is my string variable but setadapter gives me error of JAVA.lang,string something like this how can I add this string variable in LIstView??

Comment: declare the `next  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Sorah);` in your activity , not in onClick

Comment: I think the problem with `this` which should be a context . use `Next.this` instad of `this` as a first parameter of the `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Let me make it more simple I want to show String value on screen which is very large as you Know Surah of Quran that so why I am not using textView but is there any way that user can slide textView up or down to read the Full text????

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. Log the size of surah.toCharArray().length , 

Also can you please post the `sorah` layout ?

Comment: this is my Sorah layout.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/Sorah"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Layout is ok, Check the value of `surah.toCharArray().length`

Comment: This would show one character on each lineitem... Is that really the expected behavior that is wanted?